# pyqt5 - qtextedit - Input Language

Tags: pyqt5, qtextedit

Is there a way to change the input keyboard layout in a Qt app? I want to be able to input in the same QTextEdit Widget in English and Russian by switching between  languages frequently. One option is to have the cyrillic keyboard activated on Windows and switching between input languages using the windows key and the spacebar.

I want to bypass the feature though on the os level and implement it directly in my app by defining a shortcut or a push button to select the input language. The reason being that the end users (Russian speakers) will be using the app on an English language PC and they should not have to fiddle around with OS settings in a foreign language. The keyboards in use have an English layout with additional Cyrillic characters so typing should not be a problem.

I want to ask if there is a direct method (it would make sense to have one, i hope I am just unable to find it). I could overload the keyPressEvent for my widget as a last alternative. I just hope that there is a better way to do it since I am switching between standard languages.

Comment: Qt does not have any built-in APIs for switching keyboard layouts.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. This means I have to override the keyPressEvent for my QWidget, right?

Comment: My gut feeling is that is not the best way to go. If you're on Windows, you could try using [win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__LoadKeyboardLayout_meth.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I was able to load the keyboard layout automatically and then toggle between keyboard layouts the moment my app goes out of focus by using win32api.keybd_event. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Please look this https://github.com/jMultilingual/virtualkeyboard_english

This page will give you a hint to meet your demand.

1. Overriding keyPressEvent.
2. Returning cyril characters instead of the texts of QKeyEvent.
3. Making QMenu for switching the language.

for example,

```
#class QTextEdit

def keyPresEvent(self, event):
    
    if self.isCurrentWritingSystem == "Russian":
        #If you use english keyboard...
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
            tc = self.textCursor()
            tc.insertText("ф")
            return
        ... for others ↓
    else:
        #codes for normal russian keyboard you don't need to do anything.
        return super().keyPressEvent(event)
```

On the other hand, if you use russian keyboard as default.

```
    if self.isCurrentWritingSystem == "English":
        #if you use russian keyboard...
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
            tc = self.textCursor()
            tc.insertText("a")
            return
    else:
        #codes for normal english keyboard. you don't need to do anything.
        return super().keyPressEvent(event)
```