# How can I set Persian language as default QTextEdit in PyQt5?

Tags: python, character-encoding, pyqt5, qtextedit, farsi

I want to write a notepad in python with PyQt5 for Persian language, but the problem is that there is no default Persian language in it. When I use "setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)" English is written in right and Persian in left!!!
This is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QLocale

class TextBox(QTextEdit):
    def persian(self):
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)

        self.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.setLocale(QLocale(QLocale.Persian, QLocale.Iran))
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.GUI()

    def GUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("My title")
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)

        self.text = TextBox(self)
        self.text.persian()


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered here

[qtextedit - Input Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000387/pyqt5-qtextedit-input-language/75454857#75454857)

If you override keyPressEvent and returns appropriate characters,

you can input persian language.

The connection of characters will be automatically done by appropriate fonts.

I'm sorry. This is the answer for the same kind of question.

But I have only 25 reputation so , I couldn't post this message as comment.

And please execute my code here.

[github](https://github.com/jMultilingual/virtualkeyboard)